# Controlling POSIX threads with user input

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have a thread which plays an mp3 using ao_lib in C. I need someway of skipping to the next mp3 halfway through playing, so after creating the thread which plays an mp3, I have tried to create another thread which would wait for a user to enter a character and if the first one joins before the second then the second is also killed.

```
main()
{
    ret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, func_play, (void *) url);
    ret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, func_char, NULL);

    /* I need to somehow do something here to break func_play if a user
       enters a specific char in func_char */

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(thread2);

    return 0;
}
```

That didn't work. Any solutions would be really welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. `pthread_cancel(3)`?

Comment: Please post the code the pattern sounds correct, I think it might be the implementation.

Comment: @iharob added the code, i am pretty confused what to do in the comment area, to make sure that what the user enters is read, before the thread1 exits by itself

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to enable compiler warnings if you are using gcc or clang/llvm then `-Wall -Werror` would help a lot, I see that either you are ignoring warnings or not enabled them at all because your `main()`'s signature is wrong, it should return `int`, and if it's meant to take no arguments then `int main(void)` would be correct. Also remember that there is no synchornization guarantee, the second function might start before the first.

Comment: Maybe you need to share data among threads, for example instead of passing `url` pass a `struct` with a flag to end the loop where the `mp3` is being played + the `url`, you should be careful to prevent race conditions by using a mutex, you can't allow both threads to try accessing the shared data simultaneously.

Comment: @iharob thanks for your help, i do have everything set up correctly regarding the compiler, with warnings. The thing is, that there is no loop that plays the mp3, its a blocking function ao_play()

Comment: @iharob so the problem here is how do i exit a thread thats using `ao_play()` that is blocking, using user input, before the mp3 reaches its end?

Comment: Actually, i think i can pass a struct with a flag to break the mp3 playing, but how do i change that flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the pattern that I think would work, I don't know how the *mp3* playing function works, but you need it to be non-blocking, perhaps read the *.mp3* file and play it in chunks, so you can break the main loop (_the loop that plays the *.mp3*) using something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

static pthread_mutex_t mutex;

struct SharedData
{
    const char *url;
    int stop;
    int ready;
};

void *
mainloop(void *data)
{
    struct SharedData *sharedData;
    int ready;
    int stop;

    sharedData = data;
    if (sharedData == NULL)
        return NULL;

    stop  = 0;
    ready = 0;
    while (ready == 0)  
     {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        ready = sharedData->ready;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        usleep(1000);
     }

    while (stop == 0)
     {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        stop = sharedData->stop;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        printf(".");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
     }
    return NULL;
}

void *
controlthread(void *data)
{
    int                chr;
    struct SharedData *sharedData;

    sharedData = data;
    if (sharedData == NULL)
        return NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sharedData->ready = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    printf("Press return to stop the main loop...\n");
    while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'))
        usleep(1000);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    sharedData->stop = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct SharedData data;
    pthread_t         threads[2];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, mainloop, &data);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, controlthread, &data);

    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```